# What is a "friendly third-party" cookie?

Tags: cookies, web-analytics, adobe-analytics

I hear that some web analytics solutions or consultants recommand the use of "friendly third party cookies".

- How do they differ from "regular" 3rd party cookies?
- What are there pro & cons compared to usual 3rd and 1st party cookies?

Answer (score 0):

- The difference is only in the name of the domain the cookie comes from. The domain name of a 'friendly' 3rd-party cookie may be similar to the 1st-party domain - making it appear 'friendly', as opposed to a potentially 'non-friendly' unknown/unrelated 3rd-party domain.
- To a browser, the cookie is still considered '3rd-party' (i.e. not from the current host domain). To a user, they may be more willing to accept the cookie (if they are given a choice), or maybe less likely to delete it later, if the domain name appears familiar.
- A 3rd-party cookie (if the browser/user accepts it) can maintain the identity of a single visitor across multiple domains. This is why they are considered a privacy concern. If you use 1st-party cookies on multiple domains, the visitor would receive a unique visitor ID cookie from each site on arrival (unless you use something like Google Analytics cross-domain tracking on all inter-site links to stitch the ID's together.)

Comment: Thank you Nils. I have an additional question: if this "friendly" cookie uses the same domain as the 1st party (your 1st bullet point), then why do browsers consider it as a 3rd party cookie (your 2nd bullet point)?

Comment: Because it depends on the context (the host of the page). If the cookie is from exactly the same domain as the host (or a sub-domain) it is 1st-party to that domain. If you refer to that cookie from a different domain, it will be considered 3rd-party to that domain. Browser acceptance will be inconsistent if the friendly 3rd-party cookie is also 1st-party on some domains in your group.

Comment: Another downside to 3rd-party cookies is that they are generally not accessible via JavaScript, in case you need to interpret or manipulate the data.